Find modal values in each row, with custom tie breaking in PostreSQL
I have table like
create table  vals (k, v, z, y, m) AS VALUES 
(0, 0, 1, 8, 0), 
(1, 2, 1, 1, 6), 
(1, 0, 0, 2, 2),
(5, 4, 6, 8, 9), 
(0, 0, 0, 6, 6);

I want to calculate modal value for each row. If there are multiple modal values, return such value, that occurs first.



k
v
z
y
m
modal




0
0
1
8
0
0


1
2
1
1
6
1


1
0
0
2
2
0


5
4
6
8
9
5


0
0
0
6
6
0




In the 3rd row values 0 and 2 are equally frequent but 0 occurs first so it wins.
In the 4th row all values are equally frequent but 5 occurs first so it wins.

How can I do it in PostreSQL?

There's a mode function, but it's an aggregate, not a variadic. In each row, you can stuff the values into an array, unnest it, then pass that to the function. If the values are really integers, you can put them in an intarray, sort() it and grab the value under the middle index, truncated/rounded down from half the array length.

@Zegarek If there are multiple modal values, return such value, that occurs first, so we can't find it by sorting

@Zegarek could you please give more detail about how I can stuff the values into an array and unnest it?

By getting one that occurs first before sorting do you mean you need to get a 3 from [1,3,2,4], instead of a 2?

If you have more than 3 columns of numeric data, then I suggest normalizing all the data into one column.

@Zegarek I need modal, not median value

Here's one example with arrays and one with unpivoting, both using mode()within group(order by e): demo. Modal value is exactly what the mode() function returns, according to this definition. Wiki: Most frequent value in a data set. Postgres: Computes the mode, the most frequent value of the aggregated argument (arbitrarily choosing the first one if there are multiple equally-frequent values).

The new example is inconsistent or self-contradictory: if you want the larger of all equally frequent values to win, then in the 4th row with 5,4,6,8,9 it should be the 9 that wins and that's how 2 wins over 0 in the 3rd row with 1,0,0,2,2. If the one earlier in the unordered list wins, then the 4th row stays as it is, and in the 3rd row it's 0 that should win.

PostgreSQL has a built-in mode()within group(order by e) function:

mode () WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY anyelement ) → anyelement
Computes the mode, the most frequent value of the aggregated argument (arbitrarily choosing the first one if there are multiple equally-frequent values). The aggregated argument must be of a sortable type.

Which matches the Wikipedia definition of a modal value:




Type
Description
Example
Result




Arithmetic mean
Sum of values of a data set divided by number of values
(1+2+2+3+4+7+9) / 7
4


Median
Middle value separating the greater and lesser halves of a data set
1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9
3


Mode
Most frequent value in a data set
1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9
2




The function is an ordered-set aggregate, not a variadic, so you'd have to pretend values in each row are a column. You can pack them into an array[], then unnest() it, then process it and return that, all inside a correlated scalar subquery:
demo at db-fiddle
WITH arrs as(select *,array[k, v, z, y, m] as arr 
             from vals)
select k, v, z, y, m
      ,(select mode()within group(order by e) 
        from unnest(arr) as e) as modal
from arrs;

Or try unpivoting, then re-aggregating:
WITH one_column as(select ctid,k as c from vals
                   union all
                   select ctid,v from vals
                   union all
                   select ctid,z from vals
                   union all
                   select ctid,y from vals
                   union all
                   select ctid,m from vals)
select min(vals.k)
      ,min(vals.v)
      ,min(vals.z)
      ,min(vals.y)
      ,min(vals.m)
      ,mode()within group(order by c)
from one_column
join vals on one_column.ctid=vals.ctid
group by ctid;

Your updated example breaks ties in a different way than mode() does:

arbitrarily choosing the first one if there are multiple equally-frequent values

It looks like what you want is for the one earlier in the unordered list to win.
To achieve that behaviour, you can just count(*) values in each row (packed into array[], then unnest()ed), sort this by placing most frequent first, and break ties by promoting the one that appeared earlier. unnest()with ordinality adds the information about the original position of the unpacked element.
demo at db-fiddle
WITH arrs as(select *,array[k, v, z, y, m] as arr 
             from vals)
select k, v, z, y, m
      ,(select e 
        from unnest(arr)with ordinality as _(e,ordinality)
        group by e
        order by count(*) desc
                ,min(ordinality) asc--earlier in the undordered list wins
                --,e desc--larger one wins
        limit 1)
from arrs;

To get all modal value candidates, you can use fetch first 1 rows with ties. This also uses a special array() constructor that accepts a subquery directly:
demo at db-fiddle
WITH arrs as(select *,array[k, v, z, y, m] as arr 
             from vals)
select k, v, z, y, m
      ,array(select unnest(arr)e
             group by e
             order by count(*) desc
             fetch first 1 rows with ties
       ) as all_modal_value_candidates
from arrs;

In older versions of PostgreSQL, you can emulate that using rank()over():
WITH arrs as(select *,array[k, v, z, y, m] as arr 
             from vals)
select k, v, z, y, m
      ,(select array_agg(e)
        from(select unnest(arr)e, rank()over(order by count(*) desc)
             group by e)_
        where rank=1
       ) as all_modal_value_candidates
from arrs;


Great answer! Thank you very much!

How should I change your query to obtain all modals in array? So for (k, v, z, y, m) = (1, 0, 0, 2, 2) a new one column modal would be created with value array[0, 2] ?

Edit the subquery to limit 2 instead of 1, nest what it currently does on level down, and array_agg(e) from that. That'll get you the 2 most frequently occuring values. Demo

I guess I try to do something strange, cant understand:( WITH arrs as(select *,array[k, v, z, y, m] as arr
from vals)
select k, v, z, y, m,
array_agg((
  select e 
    from unnest(array[k, v, z, y, m])with ordinality as _(e,ordinality)
    group by e
    order by count(*) desc
            ,min(ordinality) asc
    )
    )

from arrs
group by k, v, z, y, m

I've pasted a working demo above, the example is right up top. It's a bit cleaner if you run array_agg still inside the scalar subquery where there's no need to group by because in that setting, it only sees the list that corresponds to the current row's array and nothing else.

No problem. Note that Tim's questions had to be asked for you to clarify the problem, for anyone to be able to solve it - and he wasn't technically wrong. That's important help too. Good luck with your coding

Im sorry but this is not quite what I needed, I want:
5 4 6 8 9 {5,4,6,8,9}
0 0 1 8 0 {0}
0 0 0 6 6 {0}
1 0 0 2 2 {0,2}
1 2 1 1 6 {1}

Ok, so not top two, but all the top ties. That's doable as well

no, this query gives more than 1 value even if mode is really one

Yes, that's what I mean by all the top ties. What you showed is the top value with all its ties. If all 5 values are equally frequent, they are all ties and you get all 5. If there's just 1, you get 1. If there's 2, you get both.

Here you go: demo. It's enough to remove the tie-breaking order by expression and replace limit with fetch first 1 rows with ties. That way all top most frequent values are ties and they all get returned to the array_agg() waiting outside.

I have 9.4 postresql, here I see error 'ERROR: syntax error at or near "with ties"' :(

No problem. You can emulate fetch first 1 rows with ties using rank()over(): demo. Be sure to update, 9.4 is not supported and hasn't been for a while.

it's like magic) thank you!!!

Assuming only three value columns, we can handle your requirement using CASE expressions:
SELECT k, v, z,
    CASE WHEN k = v OR z = k THEN k
         WHEN v = z THEN v
         ELSE k END AS modal
FROM vals;

Demo
The logic here is that if we can find two columns in agreement, then by definition their common value must be the mode of the three columns.  If we cannot find any pair with a common value, then we default to returning the first value, which is the k column.

there are three columns here just for example, really I need to do if for more columns

"really I need to do if more columns" => then you didn't ask the right question.  We only answer based on the question and sample data, right?

Swapping = for is not distinct from would make it null-safe but I don't think it's enough for an instant downvote. It's the optimal solution to the question as it was initially phrased.
